# Draw transparent-to-white gradient over white in iOS

Tags: ios, transparency, drawrect, linear-gradients, cagradientlayer

I have an iOS app with text on the main screen that scrolls. I want the text to fade out at the bottom of the screen. So I make a custom view and do something like this in `drawRect`:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat gradLocs[] = {0, 1};
CGColor *color1 = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
CGColor *color2 = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
CFArrayRef arr = (CFArrayRef)@[(id)color1, (id)color2];
CGGradientRef grad = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, arr, gradLocs);

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, grad, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(0, rect.size.height), 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Basically, draw a linear gradient from clear to white over the view.  I've also tried doing it with a `CAGradientLayer`:

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
layer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
layer.locations = @[@(0), @(1)];
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
[self.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

Either way, if this gets drawn over top of white, I get gray. [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) shows the same thing:

[image: PaintCode screenshot]

Why is this? It seems like the gradient shouldn't be visible at all over top of just white.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`+[UIColor clearColor]` is in fact transparent black. Since you want transparent white you should use:

```
color1 = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0].CGColor;
```

Reading the documentation carefully to `+[UIColor clearColor]` it says that it will return a color with grayscale and alpha values `0.0`. So the middle in your gradient from white to transparent is `[UIColor initWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5]`, i.e. transparent gray.

Comment: god bless you!!